# Mid-points of all sides and diagonals of a regular 2014-gon

Tags: geometry, combinatorial-geometry

This is an interesting problem I came across:

> In a regular 2014-gon, all mid-points of all sides and diagonals are
>   marked. What is the maximal number of such points that belong to a
>   same circle?

I don't know how to tackle it. Of course, some programming could be applied. Is there some solution without programming (although I would accept Mathematica or Matlab code as a valid answer)? And, is 2014 the answer, or some larger number (most likely multiple of 2014)?? I couldn't intuitively answer that.

What about any regular polygon? Does, lets say, primality of number of sides affect the answer in such case?

Comment: As a start, the midpoints of all the sides are on the same circle, so 2014 points are on the same circle. Can you find more than that using the midpoints of the diagonals?

Comment: @martycohen Midpoints of all diagonals and sides from a vertex also are on a circle (and there are 2013 of them). However, the center of the polygon is also mid point of 1007 diagonals, so that circle would contain 2013 + (1007 - 1) = 3019 mid-points... But, this is of course not the proof that 3019 is a max number...